# How to disable "Alarms only" mode that activates during each call?

Tags: 7.1-nougat, do-not-disturb, motorola-moto-e4

On my Moto E4 / Android 7.1.1 the "Alarms Only" mode auto-activates itself during each call.

[image]

It happens during every call, no matter, if this is placed or received call.

As you can see on following images, all my "Do Not Disturb" settings are purely default and all my automatic rules are set to "Off". Thus I have no idea what can be causing such behavior.

Things that I tried so far:

1. I have two other Motos (G4 and E3). I have checked them. Turned out that all three has exactly the same configuration and only E4 works this way.
2. I have deleted all automatic rules (thinking that maybe "Off" is not enough, since this is Google), but that brought no help.

How can I disable this feature or change my phone's behavior?

Comment: It's stock android behaviour, it is supposed to be because if you get notifications while on a call your phone should not vibrate in your ear. I do not think it is possible to turn it off. Maybe you can try an alternate dialer.

Comment: See https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-automatically-disable-do-not-disturb-mode-during-phone-calls/ @SSS is right. This is intentional behavior and is limited to stock dialer app. Changing the dialer app or use an automation app to toggle DND should work.

Comment: Funny (surprising) thing that this stock behavior can be observed only in E4 and is not existing in G4 and E3 (and also wasn't in G5 that I have for some time). Shouldn't all Moto-like phones be as "pure" and as close to stock as possible? Anyway, your comments are full-featured answer to me, so why don't you write it, so we can get you some rep.?